# How to convert string to dateTimePicker format in C#?

Tags: c#

I am fetching data from database in datatable's object called `dt`. I want to convert that string in to `dateTimePicker`'s format.

I have tried this code but its not working .

```
dtpPlanDate.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(dt.Rows[0]["PlanSDate"].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it gives me this error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I also tried another format:

```
dtpPlanDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["PlanSDate"].ToString());
```

it gives me error

> Could not determine the order of year, month, and date from
>   'mm/dd/yyyy'.

I also tried one more format

```
dtpPlanDate.Value =DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["PlanSDate"].ToString());
```

it gives me below error

> Could not determine the order of year, month, and date from
>   'mm/dd/yyyy'.

please let me know right format

Comment: What value are you getting from: dt.Rows[0]["PlanSDate"].ToString()

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **PLEASE** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Comment: In fact all your methods are correct, but answer which is the best that you need provide value of `dt.Rows[0]["PlanSDate"].ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your parameter while fetching from the database :
use this :

```
CONVERT(CHAR(10), PlanSDate, 101) AS PlanSDate
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!